# Windows Azure Blob Storage download with Shared Access Signature and CUSTOM response header

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I use the Windows Azure Blob Storage to keep files there.
To download files i create urls with Shared Access Signature.
It works fine, but there is one problem.
Some files (blobs) have the header "Content-Type" set during upload and other no.
if a file has no Content-Type than on request to Azure the response will have the header Content-Type: application/octet-stream . This is exactly what i need, because in such case a browser will show "Download dialog" for a user.

But for files where this header was set on upload, it is returned and sometimes it makes a problem. For example, Content-Type: images/jpeg makes a browser to show this image, but not download it (does not show Download dialog)

So, my question is
is there a way on download with presigned url from WIndows Azure to force to use some specific response header?
I want it behave like there is no Content-Type saved for a file, even if it is saved

Answer (score 1):

So, after some time browsing i finally found the documentation about it.

There are references.
https://nxt.engineering/en/blog/sas_token/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas

For me it was needed to up the version of the API (i used the 2012 API version).

Also one useful note. It is very sensetive to a date format. The expiraton time must be in the format like "2021-11-16T04:25:00Z" .

I have added 2 new arguments
'rscd=file;%20attachment&rsct=binary&'.
and both of the must be in the signature string to sign on their correct places

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is is there a way on download with presigned url from
> WIndows Azure to force to use some specific response header? I want it
> behave like there is no Content-Type saved for a file, even if it is
> saved

Yes, you can override [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header in your SAS Token and the blob will be always downloaded regardless of it’s content type.

You can override this header to a value like `attachment; filename=yourdesiredfilename` and the blob will always be downloaded with `yourdesiredfilename` name.